# multiple sub domains with varnish

Tags: nginx, varnish

Now I have this setup

Port 80 redirects to port 443 with nginx, then it use varnish as upstream, now when it comes back, I need to setup some variables in nginx, fx

My domains are with subdomains such as `en.mydomain.com`, `de.mydomain.com`

```
server {
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  listen 8080;
  $VAR = en;
}

server {
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  listen 8080;
  $VAR = de;
}
```

How do I figure out which domain was used to get to this - I think I need to have multiple ports and then varnish should redirect to each backend depending on the domain, how do I set varnish to return to a backend depending on the domain?

Answer (score 0):

If the IP address and the port of your Varnish backend is the same for each subdomain, you shouldn't worry about this: the `Host` header of each request will result in different cache keys in Varnish, but Nginx will also serve the right website based on this `Host` header.

In the config you shared, you should make sure `en.mydomain.com` and `de.mydomain.com` are part of the Nginx `server_name`. This will allow Nginx to match the right hostname.

If you go to `en.mydomain.com`, Varnish will extract the host and the URL, and will turn this into a unique cache key. If it needs to fetch data from Nginx, Nginx will handle it for you.